# How to run JavaFX program

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I am following this tutorial: [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm)

I have successfully built it using

`javac --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -d . -Xmaxerrs 1 HelloWorld.java`

and archived it using

`jar cfm j.jar manifest helloworld/*.class`

then ran it using

`java -jar j.jar`

and then I got the error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class helloworld.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

To be clear, there are many questions about JavaFX here, however they all seem to deal with pre-Java 8, where you need to add jfxrt.jar to the classpath. But since [JavaFX is now a separate module from Java JDK](https://jaxenter.com/javafx-separate-module-jdk-142253.html), these answers do not seem to apply anymore.

(Yes, I have installed java-openjfx package on Linux.)

I'm not sure if what I'm missing is JavaFX specific or something more general to 'linking' jar files/modules in Java.

---

### Edit:

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986287/runtimeexception-package-jdk-internal-jimage-decompressor-in-module-jrt-fs-and), I copied my JavaFX lib folder (minus jrt-fs.jar), included javafx.graphics in my added modules, and added the modules when running (as Nand commented below), and now this is the error I'm getting. Still not sure what's going on.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createTKStage(QuantumToolkit.java:600)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.doVisibleChanging(Stage.java:1154)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage$1.doVisibleChanging(Stage.java:182)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper.visibleChangingImpl(StageHelper.java:57)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.visibleChanging(WindowHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1064)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at helloworld.HelloWorld.start(HelloWorld.java:29)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle, locale en_US
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1582)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:932)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.<clinit>(WindowStage.java:101)
    ... 21 more
Exception running application helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Comment: Provide the module path and add modules in the `java` command as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I have tried the following to no avail: `java --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -jar j.jar`

Comment: Check this out: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx, and if that doesn't work, check out the "Runtime images" part

Comment: I think this is the right track. While I don't have it solved yet, it appears my main issue may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986287/runtimeexception-package-jdk-internal-jimage-decompressor-in-module-jrt-fs-and)

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you start using an IDE (e.g. IntelliJ or Eclipse), those make programming much more fun :)

Comment: Normally, if I weren't using C/C++, then I would just use Java Swing, which has no external dependencies/modules like JavaFX. But since I must use JavaFX, then I may be forced to use other tools like that, unfortunately.