# Get an error when making a Hello World program

Tags: java

I was following a basic YouTube tutorial and when I ran the code it gave this error message. Don't know what I need to do...

Code:

```
public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

Error Message:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor in both module jrt.fs and module java.base

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986287/runtimeexception-package-jdk-internal-jimage-decompressor-in-module-jrt-fs-and

Comment: You installed Java 14. That's brand new. Either downgrade Java to 11, or try and find a newer version of VS Code. Or use a different IDE that supports Java 14 (if you can find one).

Comment: There is a discrepancy in your project setup, because the tree on the left shows Java **13**, but the command in the Console shows Java **14**.

Comment: How many java versions do you have and what is the version of the eclipse that you are using?