# Java coding error: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java, error-handling

when I try to run my code I am presented with [image]

I am new to java and do not know how to processed. I have found it difficult to install eclipse onto my Mac so that may have something to do with it. If anyone has a clue on how I should processed it would be very much helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, do not post images of code or of error messages, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I also found eclipse hard to use when I was starting programming. I tried it because it was what the "cool people" were using. Never floated my boat. I recommend trying IntelliJ IDEA. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?fromIDE=&section=mac

As for your error, I've never seen it my entire 10 years of programming in Java. It looks like it's because you need to remove jrt.fs from your dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74772599/4425643 The way you are launching your application might be incorrect. You should run as Java Application instead of `new configuration`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor in both module jrt.fs and module java.base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772599/package-jdk-internal-jimage-decompressor-in-both-module-jrt-fs-and-module-java-b)